# Does Javascript have a way to simplify multiple checks for a value to be one of?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
if (tes.test.userTestStatusId != UserTestStatus.MarkedByAdmin &&
    tes.test.userTestStatusId != UserTestStatus.MarkedByUser &&
    tes.test.userTestStatusId != UserTestStatus.Paused &&
    tes.test.userTestStatusId != UserTestStatus.Completed) {
```

Is there some way I could simplify this so as not to repeat "tes.test.userTestStatusId" each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If strict equality is OK, you can store the values as an array and use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var statuses = [UserTestStatus.MarkedByAdmin, ...];

if (statuses.indexOf(userStatusId) === -1) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can cache the value

```
var userId = tes.test.userTestStatusId;

if (userId != UserTestStatus.MarkedByAdmin &&
    userId != UserTestStatus.MarkedByUser &&
    userId != UserTestStatus.Paused &&
    userId != UserTestStatus.Completed) 
{
```

put the status in an array

```
var statuses = [ UserTestStatus.MarkedByAdmin,  UserTestStatus.MarkedByUser, UserTestStatus.Paused, UserTestStatus.Completed];
```

now check the index

```
if ( statuses.indexOf( userId ) == -1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't be much less code, but it will be much more stable — you'll be able to add/remove cases from the status object without having to change the code.

The idea is to iterate through `UserTestStatus` properties and look for any that match:

```
if (!Object.keys(UserTestStatus).some(function(key) {
  return UserTestStatus[key] == test.test.userTestStatusId;
})) {
  // no matches found
}
```

Now if you come back and add a new case (maybe `UserTestStatus.Failed` or `UserTestStatus.NotStarted`) that code won't have to change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
if (![
  'MarkedByAdmin',
  'MarkedByUser',
  'Paused',
  'Completed'
].some((p) => UserTestStatus[p] === tes.test.userTestStatusId)) {
  // ...
}
```

But I personally think that the vanilla conditional approach is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can save the id in a new var and then use it in the if condition like below:

```
var statusId=tes.test.userTestStatusId;
if ( statusId!= UserTestStatus.MarkedByAdmin &&
statusId != UserTestStatus.MarkedByUser &&
statusId != UserTestStatus.Paused &&
statusId != UserTestStatus.Completed) {
```

But if you are looking for the way to combine multiple logical check in a single usage, it will not be effective as far as I know